# Python convert string to time

Tags: python, string, time, time-format

I have continues time data list with min:sec.msec and it is like,

```
t=['10:44.7',...,'36:25.1',..,'59:59.9',..,'00:00.1',...,'18:01.2']
```

This includes `min:sec.msec` but I need to convert all the data format to `Hour:min: sec`. It means data should be,

```
t_converted=['12:10:45',...,'12:36:25',..,'13:00:00',..,'14:00:00',..,'14:18:01']
```

How can I do using python?

Comment: Please clarify the rule how to get the hour values. This is not obvious yet.

Answer (score 1):

A simple time conversion can be done with

```
t_converted = [datetime.strptime(_t, '%M:%S.%f').strftime('%H:%M:%S') for _t in t]
```

The apparent requirement for everything to be offset by 12 hours makes it more complex
Firstly, the only way of knowing when to go from 12, 13 is for the next time to be less than the previous
e.g. 59:59.9, 00:00.1
If you had 30:30.0 then 45:00.0 and they were meant to be 12:30:30 and 13:45:00 there is literally no way of knowing

From that assumption, this code works:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

t=['10:44.7','36:25.1','59:59.9','00:00.1','00:00.0','18:01.2']
t_converted = []
i = 0
prev_dt = None
for _t in t:
    dt = datetime.strptime(_t, '%M:%S.%f') + timedelta(hours=12+i)
    if prev_dt is not None and prev_dt > dt:
        i += 1
        dt += timedelta(hours=1)
    t_converted.append(dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    prev_dt = dt
print(t_converted)
```